# Flickering of Fedora 27 guest in VirtualBox on OSX host

Tags: virtualbox, fedora

**What's happening:**

`Fedora 27 x64` guest is flickering while the host seems unaffected.

**What I tried:**

1. Rebooting the guest does not seem to fix the problem.
2. Rebooting the host does not seem to fix the problem.
3. I installed `Ubuntu` and it worked properly and without flickering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know what caused the problem, but this helped:

1. I logged out of `Gnome`. You're looking at the profile selection UI right now.
2. Select the gear symbol and choose `Gnome on Xorg`.
3. The flickering was gone and the guest should now be operable.